# haml/html dropdown as a table column

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, user-interface, drop-down-menu, haml

I am displaying a table for which one column is a dropdown which also changes the state of the row

```
for ex:
    %table#bug.table
      %thead
        %tr
          %th.span3 bug name
          %th.span6 Comment
          %th.span2 State
          %th.span2 Manage

      %tbody
        - @bug.each do |ref|
          %tr
            %td= bug.name
            %td= bug.comment
            %td= bug.state
            %td= select(bug.state_events)
```

Above, bug.state_events return the next possible states in a drop down for that bug. The user can then change the state (to say fixed from open).

Whats the best way to implement this in haml/html ?

PS:
I am using Rails, haml, state_machine gems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
= select_tag "tag_name", options_from_collection_for_select(bug.state_events, "id", "name"),{ :prompt => "Select State"}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sabyasachi, this options_for_select worked for me! .Since this is a table and not a form , I am wondering if there is any helper etc that would let the user change the state of the bug in the database by using the dropdown and also grab the new states to be displayed in the dropdown ?

Comment: @codeObserver i guess there is no such helper but you can easily achieve it by calling a ajax method in the background on changing the drop-down value